# How to Start Service from NDK android?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

From Java I can start Android Service like this.

```
  Intent i = new Intent();
  i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.akt.www.myapplication",
  "com.akt.www.myapplication.TEST"));
  startService(i);
```

but I want to start the service from native C++ code.
What is the equivalent way to do that?

Comment: Do you already use ndk version of activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, it's a workaround in my opinion but there is no other documented way of doing it.

```
am startservice -n [Package Name]/[Class Name]
```

You could also attache extras with this intent by adding

```
"-es [Extra Key] [Extra Value]"
```

Comment: This stopped working on Xiaomi devices with MIUI 12